# React Router remounts component everytime

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a render function inside `App.js`.

```
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="text-center main-title">Activity Logger</h1>
        <Router>
          <NavigationBar />
          <Route exact path="/">
            {this.renderForm()}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/activitydisplay">{this.renderTable()}</Route>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The `Router` is a `BrowserRouter`. The functions it call are

```
renderForm = () => {
    if (this.state.formDataError) {
      return "Error loading data";
    }
    console.log("renderForm was called");
    return (
      <div className="mt-3">
        <ActivityForm
          machinesList={this.state.machinesList}
          operatorsList={this.state.operatorsList}
          onFormSubmit={this.postFormData}
          postSuccessCount={this.state.postSuccessCount}
          loggedOperator={this.props.cookies.get("logger") || null}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

```
renderTable() {
    if (this.state.tableDataError) {
      return "Error loading data";
    }
    return (
      <div className="mt-3">
        <ActivityDisplay
          activityData={this.state.activityData}
          machines={this.state.machinesList}
          operators={this.state.operatorsList}
          editDataHandler={this.editData}
          deleteDataHandler={this.deleteData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The components are remounted when I switch between the routes at the front end. To troubleshoot, I put logging in `renderForm` function and in the `ActivityForm` constructor. I can see the logging from `renderForm` only when the `App` component is mounted and not when I switch between routes. However, I can see the logging from `ActivityForm` constructor whenever I switch between the components at the front end using a navigation bar.

I lose all the states I had in the component because of this. The behavior I expect is that the component should not remount when I switch tabs. Can anyone please help?

Comment: what component should not remount?

Comment: Ideally both of the `ActivityForm` and `ActivityDisplay` components. I would be happy if at least the `ActivityForm` does not unmount and remount causing the constructor to run and reset all its states

Comment: can you share the repo or https://codesandbox.io

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-herschel-liu1n?file=/src/App.js.

Answer (score 1):

**React Router** does basically update the UI according to a specific state. They handle that in a very organized manner with Browser Navigation events like Back, Refresh & so on.

As we all know, when React change the UI according to a specific updated state, it will mount & unMount relevant components accordingly. https://reacttraining.com/blog/mount-vs-render/ article explains that concept very nicely.

That same behavior will apply to React Router also. When you navigate to different path, existing components can be unMount & new components can be mount according to your code.

**Route with `render` prop**

```js
return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="text-center main-title">Activity Logger</h1>
    <Router>
      <NavigationBar />
      <Router>
          <Route path="/activitydisplay" render={() => this.renderTable()} />
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => this.renderForm()} />
        </Router>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

Note - *It's better if you can pass the component into `Route` using [*render*](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop. That will make `renderForm` or `renderTable` to run before `ActivityForm` or `ActivityDisplay` mount. It will also make sure that to pass all the updated props correctly to the components where necessary.*

Let me know if you need further support.